# Compile ntpsec with refclock support

Tags: 16.04, compiling, time, ntp, gps

I'm trying to use ntpd for accurate time sync with a ublox gps module using [this](http://catb.org/gpsd/gpsd-time-service-howto.html#_feeding_ntpd_from_gpsd) tutorial on Ubuntu 16.04.

However, I'm stuck setting up ntpd to listen to the shm driver. In the 
`/var/log/ntp.log`, I get the following error:

```
05-18T10:58:56 ntpd[6687]: newpeer: addr:127.127.28.0, name:(null), cast_flags:1, flags:1
05-18T10:58:56 ntpd[6687]: ntpd was compiled without refclock support.
05-18T10:58:56 ntpd[6687]: 127.127.28.0 local addr 127.0.0.1 -> <null>
05-18T10:58:56 ntpd[6687]: newpeer: addr:127.127.28.1, name:(null), cast_flags:1, flags:21
05-18T10:58:56 ntpd[6687]: ntpd was compiled without refclock support.
05-18T10:58:56 ntpd[6687]: 127.127.28.1 local addr 127.0.0.1 -> <null>
05-18T10:58:56 ntpd[6687]: Fudge commands not supported: built without refclocks
```

I am using the [NTPsec](https://www.ntpsec.org/) fork of NTP with the following `ntp.conf` file:

```
pool pool.ntp.org iburst

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
logfile /var/log/ntp.log

restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1 mask 255.255.255.0
restrict -6 ::1

# GPS Serial data reference (NTP0)
server 127.127.28.0
fudge 127.127.28.0 refid GPS

# GPS PPS reference (NTP1)
server 127.127.28.1 prefer
fudge 127.127.28.1 refid PPS
```

It seems like I built NTP without refclock support. However, I don't find information how to include this.

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: I managed to work around this issue by using the standard ntpd distribution from apt-get.
However, it would be nice to use the improved and security-hardened NTPsec. Therefore, the issue is not closed ;-)

Comment: As of now (Sep 2017) you probably would need to compile from source, and specify a refclock option, such as    --refclock=REFCLOCKS
                        Comma-separated list of Refclock IDs to build (or "all") on the ./waf configure command. More info is available at the ntpsec site. Ntpsec is still beta software at this time, so ymmv.